# Tinymce 4.0b1 is not loading

Tags: jquery, html, tinymce

I am using these lines to load tinymce4.0b1 but its not loaded.whats the problem?

```
<script src="~/Scripts/tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/tinymce/js/tinymce/plugins/table/plugin.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/tinymce/js/tinymce/themes/modern/theme.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/Scripts/tinymce/js/tinymce/skins/lightgray/skin.min.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
    tinymce.init({
        selector: "textarea",
        plugins: ["table"],
        toolbar: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image"
    });
</script>
```

And these are my HTML lines.

```
<body>
    <div>
        <form method="post">
            <textarea name="content" style="width: 100%">salam</textarea>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

But the textarea doesnt change.

Comment: Do any of those files return a 404 error? Check to see that the paths are correct.

Comment: @Titanium I have downloaded it from the site and there were 3 kind of it.1-tinymce_4.0b1.   2-tinymce_4.0b1_jquery.   3-tinymce_4.0b1_dev.I dont know which one is the best to use and how.Could you please give me an axample of using it?

Comment: Read through this installation guide: http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Installation

Comment: I think this link is for tinymce3.I dont have any problem with tinymce3 and I can load it.But the problem is with tinymce4.

Comment: use plugins: "table", instead of plugins: ["table"],

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scripts files should be loaded after bootstrap files and the media plugin should not be use before purchasing it.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what the issue is here as your code is fine. Double check the paths to your `JS` and `CSS` files.

If you've checked that and you're still having issues, copy and paste the code below:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>TinyMCE Test</title>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<script src="tinymce.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    tinymce.init({
        selector: "textarea",
        plugins: ["table"],
        toolbar: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image"
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <form method="post">
            <textarea name="content" style="width: 100%">salam</textarea>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please check the files you are using are: 1. Pointing to the correct path and 2. Up to date